# Jenkins - Host key verification failed

Tags: linux, ssh, jenkins

While I have no problems making an SSH connection from one server to another, my Jenkins is still having a trouble connecting to the remote server while executing a managed script, which is as follows.

```
$ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

And the following is the message that is produced by Jenkins while building the project.

```
$ /bin/sh /tmp/build_step_template8225836097820612990.sh
Host key verification failed.
```

Additional information will be uploaded upon request.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways to fix that.

First one is:
Log into your Jenkins server and manually ssh to that machine and accept the key.

Second one is:
Add the following to your ssh command:

```
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

Example:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@1.1.1.1
```

Comment: After lot of head bagging. This trick solved my issue.. Thnx

Comment: Be aware that setting `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` will also allow for Man-in-the-Middle (MitM) attacks.